Attaching a $D^1$ to $S^n$
I am working on a problem and I have the space $S^n \sqcup D^1/\sim$, where $\partial D^1=S^0$ is identified with two points on $S^n$, say $p$ and $q$. In other words, I just attach $D^1$ to $S^n$ along its boundary.
I was wondering if I can assume that $p=q$ because I feel like if $p$ and $q$ are different, it will be homotopy equivalent to the case $p=q$ via just sliding $p$ to $q$. This would result in $S^n \vee S^1$.
I don't know if it is true or how to show it formally if it is and whether it can be generalized attaching higher dimensional disks. Can I deformation retract a path on $S^n$ onto a point?
Thank you in advance!

In general, if we attach $D^n$ to some topological space $X$ by two different maps $f$, $g$ s.t. $f\simeq g$, then the resulting spaces $X\cup_f D^n$ and $X\cup_g D^n$ are homotopy equivalent. You have the right idea that if $p,q$ are different then you can slide $p$ to $q$ along some path ($S^n$ is path-connected for $n\ge 1$), and this gives you a homotopy between the attaching map $S^0\to S^n$ and the constant map. It is not difficult to write down a homotopy.
